# changing size of ticklines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to change the size of the tick-lines (not the label) of a 3d plot. I've tried different methods. I can easily change the size of the tick-label and its color. But changing size of the tick-lines seems impossible. I'd appreciate any thoughts on this problem.

One of the things I've tried is the following line with trying different numbers and arguments:

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=100, labelsize=7 ,width=1, pad=0.5, right='True', color='red', tickdir='in', tick1On = 'True')
```

but width, length, and tickdir don't change anything.

I've also tried:

```
for a in (ax.w_xaxis, ax.w_yaxis, ax.w_zaxis):
    for n in a.get_ticklines():
        # n.set_sketch_params(1)
        n.set_alpha(0.5)
        n.set_mfc('red')
        n.set_mew(20)
        n.set_mec('red')
        # n.set_drawstyle('steps-pre')
        n.set_c((1,0,0,1))
        n.set_ms(100)
        n.set_ls(' ')
        n.set_lw(1.)
        n.set_solid_joinstyle('round')
        n.set_markersize(900)
        n.set_marker('.')
```

I can change all the other parameters of the tick-lines but not their color or size.

grid didn't seem to help either, since I set its visibility to False.

I'm using python 3.5.0 and matplotlib 2.1.0

Comment: I suppose the ticks of a 3D plot are lines. You cannot change the length of a line through a single property, because it is simply determined by the difference of its x and y coordinates. (E.g. a line from (0,0) to (1,0) is one unit long). Concerning color, I would guess it is determined by `set_color`. Did you try that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks for your response. I did try set_color and it didn't work.